# python error: AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I want to get the hours and minutes from the date format, example: `20160214012000`, I want to get the hours `01` and `20`.

Here is the code:

```
stop_time = time.strptime(stop_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
stop_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(stop_time))
get_program_hours = stop_time.split(":")[0]
get_program_minutes = stop_time.split(":")[1]
```

Can you please show me an example how I can get the hours and minutes from the datetime object?

Comment: Could you please include a complete, working example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `strftime`:

```
get_program_hours = stop_time.strftime('%H')
get_program_minutes = stop_time.strftime('%M')
```

If it's helpful, you can also get the values as integers:

```
get_program_hours_int = stop_time.hour
get_program_minutes_int = stop_time.minute
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, but it didn't get the minutes from the date format `20160214010500` as it will show `5` instead of `05`. How i can get the full minutes from the date format to make it to show `05`?